# Is there a CUDA binary to convert a brainwallet string to a BTC address?

Tags: address, private-key, hash

I am looking for a CUDA program which will take a single argument, a brainwallet password, and output a BTC address.  After reading through several threads on how to convert passwords to public keys, and public keys to addresses, I figured there must already be something that does this.

Any suggestions welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Brain wallets are now understood to be a very insecure way to store BTC.

The software which was the sort of final 'nail in the coffin' for the (lack of ) security of brainwallets can be found here: [Brain Flayer](https://github.com/ryancdotorg/brainflayer).

Its not CUDA software, but may be relevant to you anyways.